# odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Cannot update missing record"

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to modify an odoo 12 report, I'm going to modify the template, and then I add an inherit_id, yet this inherit_id does not work. Here is the error that appears:

```
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 754, in parse
    self.parse(rec, mode)
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 763, in parse
    exc_info[2]
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo12/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 86, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 757, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 735, in _tag_template
    return self._tag_record(record, data_node)
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 612, in _tag_record
    raise Exception("Cannot update missing record %r" % xid)
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Cannot update missing record 'account.report_invoice_document_customized'" while parsing None:43, near
<data inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
        </data>
```

Comment: Post your code so that others can better understand whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `report_invoice_document_customized` instead of `account.report_invoice_document_customized`.

Odoo automatically adds dot-separated module name to external ID of view when you inspect it in debug mode by "Edit View: Form" for example.

Using external ID with this prefix results in the error you noticed.